# shinyDirchoose GetVolumes() not returning any directories

Tags: r, shiny

As this is my first StackFlow post if I did anything improperly please let me know. I am working on my second ShinyApp.  The app is supposed to read a folder and return all the *txt files for some analysis.  I've been trying to use the shinyFiles application and shinyDirChoose function to accomplish this.  When I use getVolumes() and run my app I cannot see any of my computers files or folders.  I'm sure my code has some other errors as well but I can't even run for debugging correctly if I can't get the folder to scan in correctly.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(Cairo)  
library(DT)
library(plyr)
library(shinythemes)
library(shinyFiles)

shinyApp(

  ui = fluidPage(

  theme = shinytheme("superhero"),

  titlePanel(
      fluidRow(
          column(9, strong("Winnow Output")), 
          column(3, img(height = 150, width = 150, src = "spirit_black.jpg"))
      )
  ),

sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
    fluidRow(
      column(width=12,
             shinyDirButton('directory', 'Folder select', 'Please select a folder'),
             h3("Directory Selected"),
             verbatimTextOutput("dirpath"),

             div(class = "option_group",
                 radioButtons("plot_type", "Plot type",
                 c("Scatter", "Linear Rates", "AUC by MAE","True-Positives by False-Positives"), inline = FALSE),

                 conditionalPanel("input.plot_type === 'Scatter'",
                                  selectInput("pvar1", "x-Var",
                                              c("tp" = "tp",
                                                "fp" = "fp"
                                                ),
                                              selected = "tp"
                                  ),
                                  selectInput("pvar2", "y-Var",
                                              c("tp" = "tp",
                                                "fp" = "fp"
                                              ),
                                              selected = "fp"
                                  )
                 ),
                 conditionalPanel("input.plot_type === 'Linear Rates'",
                                  selectInput("lvar1", "x-Var",
                                              c("tpr" = "tpr",
                                                "fpr" = "fpr"
                                                ),
                                              selected = "tpr"
                                              ),
                                  selectInput("lvar2", "y-Var",
                                              c("tpr" = "tpr",
                                                "fpr" = "fpr"
                                                ),
                                              selected = "fpr"
                                              )
                                  ),
                 conditionalPanel("input.plot_type === 'AUC by MAE'",
                                  sliderInput("auc.min", "AUC axis minimum", min = 0, max = 2, value = .5,step=0.05),
                                  sliderInput("auc.max", "AUC axis maximum", min = 0, max = 2, value = 1,step=0.05),
                                  sliderInput("mae.min", "MAE axis minimum", min = 0, max = 2, value = 0,step=0.05),
                                  sliderInput("mae.max", "MAE axis maximum", min = 0, max = 2, value = 1,step=0.05)
                 )
              )#ends div
             )#ends column
    )#ends fluidRow
  )#ends sidebarPanel
      ,
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Plot",plotOutput("plot1")),
      tabPanel("Table",

               fluidRow(
                 column(4,
                        h4("means"),
                        tableOutput("meanresults")
                 ),
                 column(4,
                        h4("sums"),
                        tableOutput("sumresults")
                 ),
                 column(4,
                        h4("means"),
                        tableOutput("meanresults2")
                 )
               )#end fluidRow
      )#ends tablPale
    )#ends tabsetPanel  
  )#ends mainPanel
 )#ends sidebarLayout
),#ends ui = fluidPage





server = function(input, output) {
      roots <- getVolumes()   
      folderInput1 <- reactive({
          shinyDirChoose(input, 'directory', roots = roots, session = session, 
                         restrictions = system.file(package = 'base'))
      return(parseDirPath(volumes, input$directory))
  })

  output$directorypath = renderPrint({  folderInput1()  })

  files1 <- reactive({
      list.files(path = folderInput1(), pattern = "*.txt", full.names = T)
  })

  nFiles1 <- reactive({ length(files1() ) })
filenames <- reactive ({file_path_sans_ext(files1)})

  myfiles <- reactive({lapply(files1, function(x) read.table(x, header=TRUE))})

  tpmax<-function(list){
      tps<-list()
      for (i in 1:length(list)){
          tps[[i]]<-list[[i]]$tp
      }
      y<-unlist(lapply(tps, max))
      return(max(y))
  }
  ta<-reactive({tpmax(myfiles)})
  #Determines minimum value of all true positives
  tpmin<-function(list){
      tps<-list()
      for (i in 1:length(list)){
          tps[[i]]<-list[[i]]$tp
      }
      y<-unlist(lapply(tps, min))
      return(min(y))
  }
  tb<-reactive({tpmin(myfiles)})
  #Determines median value of all true positives
  tpmed<-function(list){
      tps<-list()
      for (i in 1:length(list)){
          tps[[i]]<-list[[i]]$tp
      }
      y<-unlist(lapply(tps, median))
      return(median(y))
  }
  tc<-reactive({tpmed(myfiles)})
  #Determines maximum value of all false positives
  fpmax<-function(list){
      fps<-list()
      for (i in 1:length(list)){
          fps[[i]]<-list[[i]]$fp
      }
      y<-unlist(lapply(fps, max))
      return(max(y))
  }
  fa<-reactive ({fpmax(myfiles)})
  #Determines minimum value of all false positives
  fpmin<-function(list){
      fps<-list()
      for (i in 1:length(list)){
          fps[[i]]<-list[[i]]$fp
      }
      y<-unlist(lapply(fps, min))
      return(min(y))
  }
  fb<-reactive({fpmin(myfiles)})
  #Determines median value of all false positives
  fpmed<-function(list){
      fps<-list()
      for (i in 1:length(list)){
          fps[[i]]<-list[[i]]$fp
          y<-unlist(lapply(fps, median))
          return(median(y))
      }
  }
  fc<-reactive({fpmed(myfiles)})




  all.data<<-reactive ({do.call("rbind", myfiles)})

  TPFP <- reactive ({ddply(all.data, .(tp, fp, filenames), summarize, count=length(filenames))})


output$plot1 = renderPlot({
  if (input$plot_type == "Scatter") {
    ggplot(all.data(),aes_string(x=input$pvar1,y=input$pvar2))+geom_point(color="firebrick")
  } else if (input$plot_type == "Linear Rates") {
    ggplot(all.data,aes_string(x=input$lvar1,y=input$lvar2))+geom_line(size = 1, alpha = 1 )+
      labs(title= "Comparison of Rates")
  }
    else if (input$plot_type == "AUC by MAE"){
        plot(myfiles[[1]]$mae, myfiles[[1]]$auc, main="Plot of AUC by MAE", xlab="Mean Absolute Error (MAE)", ylab="Area under R-O Curve (AUC)", 
             pch=21, bg="black", xlim=c(input$mae.min, input$mae.max), ylim=c(input$auc.min,input$auc.max))
        plotcol<-c("black")

         if (length(myfiles) > 1){
            #Create overlapping data plots to compare potentially by GWAS tool
            #assuming that the length of the Winnow files is at least 2
            for (i in 2:length(myfiles)){
                points(myfiles[[i]]$mae, myfiles[[i]]$auc, main="Plot of AUC by MAE", xlab="Mean Absolute Error (MAE)", ylab="Area under R-O Curve (AUC)",
                       pch=21, bg=rainbow(i+1)[i], xlim=c(input$mae.min, input$mae.max), ylim=c(input$auc.min, input$auc.max))
                plotcol[i]<-rainbow(i+1)[i]

            }
         }
    }
    else if (input$plot_type == "True-Positives by False-Positives"){
    p <- ggplot(TPFP(), aes_string(x=fp, y=tp),environment=environment())

    p2 <- p +
        geom_rect(data=all.data[1,], aes(xmin=fc, xmax=fa, ymin=tc, ymax=ta),
                  alpha=0.2, fill="blue", linetype=0) +
        geom_rect(data=all.data[1,], aes(xmin=fb, xmax=fc, ymin=tc, ymax=ta),
                  alpha=0.2,fill="green", linetype=0) +
        geom_rect(data=all.data[1,], aes(xmin=fb, xmax=fc, ymin=tb, ymax=tc),
                  alpha=0.2, fill="blue", linetype=0) +
        geom_rect(data=all.data[1,], aes(xmin=fc, xmax=fa, ymin=tb, ymax=tc),
                  alpha=0.2, fill="gray", linetype=0) +
        theme(panel.background=element_rect(fill='white', colour='black')) +
        theme(panel.grid.major=element_blank(), panel.grid.minor=element_blank()) +
        geom_point(aes(colour=filenames, size=count)) +
        scale_size_continuous(range=c(2,8)) +
        xlab("False Positives") +
        ylab("True Positives") +
        ggtitle("False Positives by True Positves") +
        xlim(0, fa) + ylim(0, ta)
    print(p2)
    }

})

output$meanresults = renderTable({apply(all.data()[,1:5],2,mean)},rownames=TRUE)

output$sumresults = renderTable(apply(all.data()[,6:9],2,sum),rownames=TRUE)

output$meanresults2 = renderTable(apply(all.data()[,10:16],2,mean),rownames=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be too late for you, but may help others.
When you use `getVolumes()`, this returns a function, then, if you want to retrieve the path, you need to use `getVolumes()()`.
I also think that `parseDirPath` may not be applied correctly.
In your case:

```
server = function(input, output) {

      roots <- getVolumes()()   

      folderInput1 <- reactive({
          shinyDirChoose(input, 'directory', roots = roots, session = session, 
                         restrictions = system.file(package = 'base'))
      return(parseDirPath(roots, input$directory))
  })
...
```